# Modifying endpoint class to list nearby places stored in the App Engine Datastore instead of all the places

Tags: android, google-app-engine, geolocation, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I just started learning about Cloud Endpoints from [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial) by Google. The sample app provided in this tutorial defines Place as a JPA entity that has a GeoPt field for storing its location in the the App-Engine backend app which can be accessed by an android client via Google Cloud Endpoints.

I want to modify the PlaceEndPoint class in this sample app to return the list of only those places stored in the datastore that are nearby the user of the Android app instead of listing all the places in the datastore. By nearby, I mean a list of those places that lie in around 30 km radius sorted by the distance from the user. I would later need to apply more filters to these results by the type of places the user wants to see.

To do this I would probably have to:
1. Pass the user's location from the android client to the App-Engine backend
2. Tweak the function listPlace() in the PlaceEndpoint class of the backend app to return places near the user

But I'm not familiar enough with App Engine and Endpoints to figure out how to go about it. Please give me any hint or direction that would be helpful. Thanks so much in anticipation!!

Here is the code for the listPlace method in the PlaceEndpoint class as contained in the Google's sample app:

```
@Api(name = "placeendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "google.com", ownerName = "google.com", packagePath = "samplesolutions.mobileassistant"))
public class PlaceEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listPlace")
    public CollectionResponse<Place> listPlace(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Place> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Place as Place");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Place>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Place obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<Place> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? How does the `Place` class look, especially the fields you want to base distance calculations on? What qualifies as "nearby", a few feet/meters, a city, a planet? Posting 100+ lines of unmodified sample code isn't helpful at all.

Comment: Hi Philipp, Thanks for responding! I have modified the original post to explain the context that you requested as best as I can. Please let me know if I can offer any more information that would be helpful.

Comment: What would be the Java method signature for querying nearby places if you would call a local method instead of a remote service? If you have that, adding the required `@Api...` annotations should be straightforward.